# Conscious Attention for Inner transformation during daily activities

Tags: mindfulness, meditation-body, mahasi-sayadaw

The life current is extremely strong, if I consciously bring my attention to a single breath, a single movement of my abdomen, a single moment of my weight or sensation of my sitting bones during daily life, would it still be beneficial to my inner transformation?

Or is it long hours of (15min plus) sitting meditation, body scanning is only counted?

Answer (score 2):

Mindfulness should be from awakening to falling asleep, i.e., throughout the day. Formal practice time is just a booster and practice to keep your mindfulness thought out the day.

Answer (score 0):

When this was said, the Blessed One addressed the monks. "Whoever develops mindfulness of death, thinking, 'O, that I might live for a day & night... for a day... for the interval that it takes to eat a meal... for the interval that it takes to swallow having chewed up four morsels of food, that I might attend to the Blessed One's instructions. I would have accomplished a great deal' — they are said to be dwelling heedlessly. They develop mindfulness of death slowly for the sake of ending the fermentations.

"But whoever develops mindfulness of death, thinking, 'O, that I might live for the interval that it takes to swallow having chewed up one morsel of food... for the interval that it takes to breathe out after breathing in, or to breathe in after breathing out, that I might attend to the Blessed One's instructions. I would have accomplished a great deal" — they are said to be dwelling heedfully. They develop mindfulness of death acutely for the sake of ending the fermentations.

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/beyondcoping/heedfulness.html